# NLP for Reference Classification

Tags: python, regex, nlp, text-classification

I need to parse several technical text documents to find every instance of references.

Using regular expressions, I easily managed to extract every mention of references, because all our documents follow naming standards.

For example : ABC0001, AB-000-001, AB-00001, etc.

The problem I am facing is that often, a text won't just reference another document, but will instead  say that it is being referenced by another document.

For example, here are 2 possible sentences:

> For further detail, go see AB-000-001.

or

> This document is used as a reference by AB-00001.

Since these sentences don't necessarily follow a pattern, I'd like to use a simple text classification model to detect whether a sentence is referencing  to another document, or is the subject of a reference.

I was inspired by this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sarcasm-text-classification-using-spacy-in-python-7cd39074f32e), but I can't find a pre-exisiting data set for my problem. Do I have to train a model from scratch, or are there simpler ways of getting the job done ?

Thanks,

Liam

PS: I'm working in Python

Answer (score 1):

Given your very specific use case, you will most likely have to prepare the dataset on your own by annotating examples from the technical documents you refer to.

You could do it semi-automatically using [Snorkel](https://www.snorkel.org/) which might be the best strategy given the relative simplicity of your task. The weighting of *[labelling functions](https://www.snorkel.org/use-cases/01-spam-tutorial)* could give you a very good classifier.

The approach that is used in the referenced article is rather heavy and requires a lot of annotated data that you don't have. Therefore, I would not try to use it unless you are willing spending weeks annotating data.